# Does the python interpreter that comes with anaconda differ from the official python interpreter distribution?

Tags: python, anaconda

I know that anaconda is a technology independent framework, but this question is specifically with respect to python.

Does the python interpreter that comes with anaconda differ from the [official python interpreter](https://www.python.org/downloads/) distribution?

For example - say I have anaconda installed and running `python --version` gives me 3.7.3, then is there a guarantee that this is the same as the python version 3.7.3 from the official source?

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10822#issuecomment-598587316 - this comment says "Our python builds (and the builds from most other distributions) contain many changes from the official releases".

Comment: In what respect is that programming related and why does the answer matter in your case?

Comment: I'm quite sure they won't develop their own python interpreter.

Comment: I hear that - their python builds contain many changes from the official release.

Comment: No, it's the exact same CPython runtime. They just package it with a lot of additional third-party libraries

Comment: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10822#issuecomment-598587316 - this comment says "Our python builds (and the builds from most other distributions) contain many changes from the official releases".